# Using paging functionality of MS Graph C# SDK, am I able to grab the NextLink and resume the call with it later?

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I understand that based on the documentation [here](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/docs/collections.md) that with the C# Graph SDK library I can continue requesting the next page of results until NextPageRequest == null, but I was wondering if I could save the NextLink I get back and if I encounter an error, the next time this is executed, I could resume at the place I was at using the NextLink (using the C# SDK library).

I haven't been able to find anything in the documentation around this. Is this perhaps something I could do with the RequestBuilder?

Comment: Another use for this would be to support user-initiated paging in the form of next-page links.  AWS Cognito exposes a simple to use `NextToken` for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out, or least a way that works using the skipToken (maybe there is a nicer built in library function way of doing this).

Example query:

```
var groupMembersPaged = await graphClient.Groups[groupId]
    .Members
    .Request()
    .Top(5)
    .GetAsync();
```

1. Extract the skipToken from the result like this:

```
var skipToken = groupMembersPaged.NextPageRequest.QueryOptions
    .Where(qo => qo.Name == "$skiptoken")
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

2. If the skipToken exists, use it in the next request:

```
if (skipToken != null)
{
    var queryOptions = new List<QueryOption>
    {
        new QueryOption("$skiptoken", skipToken.Value)
    };

    var groupMembersPagedSkip = await graphClient.Groups[groupId]
        .Members
        .Request(queryOptions)
        .GetAsync();
}
```